# Inserting text to a file with Sed within shell Script

Tags: unix, sed

I tried to insert a text to the first line
of a file using `sed`. I do this inside a `sh` 
script.

But why it hangs at the line of sed execution?

```
#! /bin/sh

# Command to execute
# ./mybashcode.sh test.nbq

nbqfile=$1   
nbqbase=$(basename $nbqfile nbq)
taglistfiletemp="${nbqbase}taglist_temp"
taglistfile="${nbqbase}taglist"


./myccode $nbqfile | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
awk '{print $2}' > $taglistfiletemp 

noftags=$(wc -l $taglistfiletemp | awk '{print $1}')
echo $noftags


# We want to append output of noftags
# to the first line of taglistfile

sed '1i\
$noftags' > $taglistfile

# why it hangs here
# the content of taglistfile is NIL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `sed` but it needs two inputs, the script (*usually a search/replace*) and the data you want to perform it on. If you only specify one it assumes it has got the regular expression and waits for data on `stdin`. As you haven't supplied anything on `stdin` it'll hang indefinitely.

In addition, you have '`$noftags`' rather than "`$noftags`". The prior will output `$noftags` and the latter the contents of the variable, as single quotes do not allow variable expansion.

Comment: another problem might be that you are using single quotes instead of double, which prevents expansion of environment variables. Thus you are literaly appending '$noftags'

Answer (score 2):

Have I got something wrong here?
Or, all you want to do is insert some text at the start of another file?

```
# $NewInitialText
# $fileToInsertInto
echo $NewInitialText > temp.file.txt
cat $fileToInsertInto >> temp.file.txt
mv temp.file.txt $fileToInsertInto
```

Is that easier done than `sed`? -- <sub>Pun intended I guess.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

it hangs because you forget to supply sed with the input file.

```
....
...
sed -i.bak "1i $noftags" $taglistfile 
...
```

Comment: I used this today, best answer right here, IMO. `$> sudo sed -i "1i /usr/local/bin /etc/path`.